# How is the default label field chosen by ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, enterprise-geodatabase, labeling, esri-geodatabase

I have 2 questions:

I know how to manually go to Layer Properties>Labels tab>Label Field and choose my label field.  I also know that I could set up my primary label field and save the setting as a layer (*.lyr) file.  This question, though, is more about how the label field is chosen by the program prior to user interaction.

First: **When a new layer (shapefile, ArcSDE layer, personal/file geodatabase featureclass) is added to ArcMap, how is the default label field chosen?**  From my experience, it isn't chosen by field order, nor alphabetical by field.  My best guess so far is that it *might* chose the first field of text/varchar (alphanumeric) type.

Second: **Is there a way to define what the "primary label field" will be for a layer within the shapefile, sde, or gdb files**, or are you stuck with saving layer files or letting the system pick for you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [this post](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=993&t=188327), the default display field is chosen according to the following priorities:

1. First field of type Text whose name contains the word "name" (case-insensitive)
2. First field of type Text
3. First field of an integer type (Long or Short, presumably)
4. First field of any type

I don't think there is any way to specify the primary display field without using a layer or layer file, other than using the above logic to name/order your fields accordingly.

Comment: That makes sense.  Thank you for finding that link!

Answer (score 1):

In ArcGIS 9.3 there is an option to set a field as primary display field.
Right click on a which you want to set as default and click properties then you find an option there as "Set as default" if you select that option.